# Connection error while creating linked service in ADF with salesforce

Tags: azure, salesforce, azure-data-factory

i m getting adf connection error while creating linked service i created it after creating self hosted IR. Below is the error

ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][Salesforce] (22) Error parsing XML response from Salesforce: not well-formed (invalid token) at line 13
ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][Salesforce] (22) Error parsing XML response from Salesforce: not well-formed (invalid token) at line 13
Activity ID: dd0d0247-0b48-487e-824a-a232662e3709.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMn9V.png)

Comment: Did you ref this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-salesforce?

Comment: Try changing the environment URL to just domain, drop the "/home/home.jsp" part

Comment: Thank you very much dropping "/home/home.jsp" part work, now the test connection is succesfull.

Comment: Hi @VaishnaviS, thanks evescream very much and we are glad to hear now the connection is succesfull. I help you post it and this can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much for @eyescream help, please drop the  `/home/home.jsp` part and it works.

We are glad to hear that now the test connection is succesfull.

I help you post it and this can be beneficial to other community members.