# Connection error while creating linked service (Synapse) Salesforce

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, salesforce, azure-data-factory

when I tried to create a linked services (Salesforce) - AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime type, I'm getting this error:

ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][Salesforce] (22) Error parsing XML response from Salesforce: not well-formed (invalid token) at line 1 ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][Salesforce] (22) Error parsing XML response from Salesforce: not well-formed (invalid token) at line 1 Activity ID: af3f6fd8-172b-4327-bac2-187863960c02.

I verified that all the credentials are correct and it shows on salesforce user login history that the login attempt was successful, but the linked service setup is throwing an error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HI1E.jpg)

Comment: Did you look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66752566/connection-error-while-creating-linked-service-in-adf-with-salesforce

Comment: yes I've seen this, I'm getting the same error but different case... I tried connecting to production instance and it works fine, I tried using a different sandbox environment and it works fine but there's one specific sandbox environment that keeps on throwing the error...

the credentials I'm putting in works fine if I tried it using rest or soap on a different application..

Answer (score 0):

As per the updated [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-xml):

> XML format is supported for the following connectors: Amazon S3,
> Amazon S3 Compatible Storage, Azure Blob, Azure Data Lake Storage
> Gen1, Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2, Azure Files, File System, FTP,
> Google Cloud Storage, HDFS, HTTP, Oracle Cloud Storage and SFTP. It is
> supported as source but not sink.

Even if it is working, you can take the reference from the files and environment for which it is working fine and correct the XML file to make it well formed.

You can also check your URL and Username once again. Also refer [linked service properties for salesforce](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-salesforce?tabs=data-factory#linked-service-properties).